# Adding Clickable Controls during a Click Event ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET webform that has a Listbox that I'm adding items to dynamically using a Button (using Session to save the list between postbacks). When an Item is added to the Listbox I want to add an ImageButton that I can click to change the color of the newly created button. I know I should be doing something differently, like adding the controls in Page_Init but then the Add Button event (`cmdAdd_Click`) hasn't gone off yet. I can't seem to figure out how to do it in a clean and simple way.

.aspx snippet:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" OnClick="cmdAdd_Click" />
<asp:ListBox ID="lboObjects" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlButtons" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

.cs code Behind Snippet:

```
protected void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    // Simplified for Brevity 
    ((List<Line>)Session["lstObjects"]).Add("Unique Object"); // the object will be unique.
    lboObjects.DataSource = ((List<Line>)Session["lstObjects"]);
    lboObjects.DataBind();

    // Clear out b/c I intend on having a cmdRemove_Click, but not showing for simplicity
    pnlButtons.Controls.Clear();

    foreach (object obj in ((List<Line>)Session["lstObjects"]))
    {
        ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();

        imageButton.ID = obj.ToString();
        imageButton.Click += cmdChangeColor_Click;
        pnlButtons.Controls.Add(imageButton);
    }
}

protected void cmdChangeColor_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{........}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to load controls inside **Page_Init**. Otherwise, they are not in control tree, and they won't be able to trigger **cmdChangeColor_Click** event.

For example,

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = Session["lstObjects"] as List<Line>;
    if (list != null)
    {
        foreach (var obj in list)
        {
            ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton {ID = obj.ToString()};
            imageButton.Click += cmdChangeColor_Click;
            pnlButtons.Controls.Add(imageButton);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the example provided, how do I get the Page_Init to happen after I execute the cmdAdd_Click Event? Do I somehow add the List and then send another Postback to process another Page_Init?

Comment: You do not need to do anything; Page_Init will fire even before Page_Load. The idea is to load the dynamically created controls to control tree. Before implementing a list of controls, start with with a single control. You can read an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37882531/296861).